# Complex gridview data: View and Edit

Tags: gridview, crosstab

I want to show and Update the data in the below format in a gridview, First column would be select checkbox to select particular records and last column is to update the record as paid or Unpaid
Total Bill Amount will give the addition of all the product cost in that billno

| select Check | Date | Bill no | Product Name | Product Cost | total bill amount | Paid/UnPaid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2-2-22 | ABC123 | aa11 | 10 | 30 |  |
|  |  |  | bb11 | 20 |  |  |
|  | 3-4-22 | AAC124 | pp12 | 25 | 100 |  |
|  |  |  | qq21 | 25 |  |  |
|  |  |  | rr54 | 50 |  |  |

It is like a crosstab data.
I am not able to decide the control to use.
Whether I should use the Table inside a grid or is there another better option ?
how to deal with it? what is the best way as the table may have many records?
Do I have to use repeater control for this?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can achive that in Gridview control itself, by using nested gridview.

Link : https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

modify as per you design requirement.